# chrome.storage.local.get not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

Here i'm using to store the multiple value[below is the code]

Here **DocName** is the Name of the PDF and  **Base64File** is the base64 string of the pdf

```
 var obj = { DocName: res.Value.DocumentName, Base64File: res.Value.Base64File };
    chrome.storage.local.set({ 'MyFile': obj });
```

In next page i'm retriving like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.sendToPdf', function(){
     chrome.storage.local.get('MyFile', function (result) {
        var PdfBase64 = result.MyFile.Base64File;
        var DocumentName = result.MyFile.DocName;
        var arr=new Array();
        var item={"CategoryID": 11,"DocumentNumber": "22022018053567","Base64FileData": PdfBase64,"DocumentName": DocumentName,
        "OptionalParam1": "sample string 5"};
        arr.push(item);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Documentupload,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': headerdata,
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            data:JSON.stringify(arr),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (res) {       
                if (res.IsSuccess) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#divLoading").hide();
                    }, 2000);
                    //$("#divLoading").hide();
                    $(".modal-iframe1").attr("src", window.emSigner.OnlineSignUrl + res.Response[0].DocumentID + "&AuthToken=" + AuthToken);
                    //window.location.reload();
                }else{
                    alert(res.Messages);
                    window.location.href='/PdfLogin.html';
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                //alert("Error while communicating to the server");
                alert(error.responseText);
                window.location.href='/PdfLogin.html';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[check this image [.sendToPdf(button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYQa4.png)]
Question is, if i click the button first time on any icon, the values are retriving correctly, but in second time if i click other than 1st icon i'm getting the values as the before one?  it is accepting the previous values only?

How to resolve this, 
Help me to come out of this problem.

Comment: I updated the latest code, please check once and i used in ajax call

Comment: The posted code still seems incomplete - it saves `MyFile` just once so obviously the value is the same.

Comment: What `icon`? Try to organize the code so it contains [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: Whenever i click the icon[.sendToPdf(button)] , i'm setting the new value but im getting the same value while retriving time, it should be different coz in this image several  icon[.sendToPdf(button)] is there